# Looping through a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've been making an IRC bot in PHP. I've given different users specific access levels between 0 and 5. 0 being a guest and 5 being an admin.

I've been trying to write a command that when a user accesses it, it will send them a list of commands and syntax that they're allowed to use.

So far I have something like this

```
$array = array
(
    "5" => $commands = array
        (
            "test" => $test2 = array
                (
                    "trigger" => "!test",
                    "descrip" => "Just testing."
                )
            "test2" => $test3 = array
                (
                    "trigger" => "!lol",
                    "descrip" => "another test."
                ) 
        ) 
);
```

I have no idea how to loop through it so that `if ($accessLevel == 5) then show commands for $array[5(and below)]`

At the end I want it to send out `$array[5][command][trigger] : $array[5][command][descrip]`

I don't necessarily need you to code it for me, just a push in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it... (check the privilege level)

```
foreach($array as $level => $priv){
    // check for privilege level
    if($level >= $accessLevel){
        // loop through privilege array
        foreach($priv as $command => $list){
            foreach($list as $trigger => $description)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

On a side note, instead of using string keys for level you could use array indicies, and that would allow the combined outer `foreach/if` combination to be written as

```
for($i = $accessLevel; $i >= 0; $i--){
   $priv = $array[$i];
   //...
}
```

Comment: I definitely like the idea of using the array indicies. That makes it a lot cleaner. Let me give this a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; --$i) {
  //list commands for accesslevel $i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (Prolly want to add newlines or delimiters)

```
foreach ($array[5] as $key=>$value) {
  echo $key;
  echo $value['trigger'];
  echo $value['descrip']; 
}
```